# Should, for a Hibernate created table, set the version column to some value at row creation?

Tags: hibernate

I have a table, created in the `Hibernate` (java) world, which is also used by a non-hibernate system (`.NET`, but can be anything). `Hibernate` uses a `version` column for transaction work purposes, and fails (detects the row as in 'transient' state) when the column is `null`.

Question... should that column (from the non-hibernate perspective) be ignored? or,
always initialized with `zero` (or other value)? or...
just set as `default 0` in the SQL which creates the table?
what is the best strategy to live sharing these tables used by Hibernate?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be sharing tables between Hibernate and non-Hibernate systems, it is imperative that the non-Hibernate systems increase the version number every time they modify the row.  This is because Hibernate optimistic locks assume that if the version number didn't change, then the row didn't change.

This also means that the other system should insert a value such as 0 or 1 when they first create the row.